# fill between two lines

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I’m trying to get a fill between two horizontal lines. However, I also want these two lines to start at the begining of the trading day and stop in the future (at the ending of the trading day ideally).
On one hand, `line.new` can plot lines in the future but can’t seems to work with `fill`. On the other hand, `plot` works with `fill` but can’t seem to be plot in from a point in the past to a point in the future… Anyone would know a solution for that ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Use the `box()` functions instead and set the bgcolor as the equivalent of a color fill.

```
lb = input(30)

hh = highest(high, lb)
ll = lowest(low, lb)

mid = avg(hh, ll)

var box box_up = box.new(left = na, top = na, right = na, bottom = na, border_color = #00000000)
var box box_dn = box.new(left = na, top = na, right = na, bottom = na, border_color = #00000000)

var line l_hh = line.new(x1 = na, y1 = na, x2 = na, y2 = na, color = color.white)
var line l_mid = line.new(x1 = na, y1 = na, x2 = na, y2 = na, color = color.white)
var line l_ll = line.new(x1 = na, y1 = na, x2 = na, y2 = na, color = color.white)

up_col = close > mid ? color.new(color.lime, 30) : #00000000
dn_col = close < mid ? color.new(color.red, 30) : #00000000

box.set_lefttop(box_up, left = bar_index - lb, top = hh)
box.set_rightbottom(box_up, right = bar_index, bottom = mid)
box.set_bgcolor(box_up, color = up_col)

box.set_lefttop(box_dn, left = bar_index - lb, top = mid)
box.set_rightbottom(box_dn, right = bar_index, bottom = ll)
box.set_bgcolor(box_dn, color = dn_col)

line.set_xy1(l_hh, x = bar_index - lb, y = hh)
line.set_xy2(l_hh, x = bar_index, y = hh)

line.set_xy1(l_mid, x = bar_index - lb, y = mid)
line.set_xy2(l_mid, x = bar_index, y = mid)

line.set_xy1(l_ll, x = bar_index - lb, y = ll)
line.set_xy2(l_ll, x = bar_index, y = ll)
```

With your condition, so as above with `up_col` you could do the condition something along the lines of

`up_col = hh - ll >= 10 ? color.new(color.lime, 30) : #00000000`

Comment: I have very few knowledge in Pinescript. What I coded so far is copy/paste from existing scripts. I found Pivot Boxes [LM] by lmatl but he uses `bar.new` and I struggle to get the left and right sides plot like I want… Could you give me a example please ?
I forgot to mention that I want the fill (or the box) only if the difference between two lines is >= 10.
My lines are price lines like OHLC of daily period.

Comment: Thanks for that code. I sligthly changed it and added `box.set_extend` because it is the only way I found to have the box start at the begining of the trading session while have it continued beyond actual price bar. I tried to work with `bar_index`, in vain.
However, I’d rather have the right side of the box to stop at the end of the trading day (just like TradingView’s built-in Standard Pivot Point). If you have any clue of how to do it I would greatly appreciate.